# Linq match item in lookup column with multiple entries

Tags: linq, contains, lookup

I have list `A` that has a lookup to list `B` that allows multiple entries. One `A` to multiple related `B`s - standard practice. I want to find `A` where `B` contains a reference to a particular instance of 'b'.

I've tried:

```
var As = from a in ARecs where a.Bs.Contains(b) select a;
```

But I get the usual 'multiple tables involved' error.  How do I go about this please?

thanks in advance

the error I'm getting is "The query uses unsupported elements, such as references to more than one list, or the projection of a complete entity by using EntityRef/EntitySet."

The A and B list code is generated by SPMetal if that makes any difference

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you're getting?

Comment: Your Linq query is a valid one (it should work if circumstances surrounding it are correct). We need more information on the error, along with more detail on your code to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: The error I'm getting is The query uses unsupported elements, such as references to more than one list, or the projection of a complete entity by using EntityRef/EntitySet.

Answer (score 0):

Some LINQ cannot be turned into CAML (did I forget to mention this was on SPMetal generated LINQ to Sharepoint - doh!) and needs to be performed as 2 queries - the first ToList then the 2nd on that list.  This worked for me.

```
Var Bs = A.ToList().Where(record => record.Bs.Contains(b))
```